# Is it possible to publish a Webjob as "Triggered" type as well as "Continuous" type

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have a console application that has been converted to a Webjob.

There are a lot of functionalities in the webjob that is required to be run once a every night(midnight).

However, there is also a specific need that the same Webjob should be continuously running to do some jobs and be able to queue the requests from multiple users.

As the most of the processes are the same I don't see the point of creating another console application as type "Continuous".

As we have a continuous delivery in azure( when there is a new commit to git the online visual studio builds and release the web app and webjobs automatically).

How can I manage to tell build or release process to create 2 webjobs from the same console application which one of those is scheduled(Triggered) and the other is "Continuous"?

While I was writing up the question, stackoverflow similar questions highlighted me this question : [Azure webjob; Scheduled execution as well triggers by queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076661/azure-webjob-scheduled-execution-as-well-triggers-by-queue)

It looks like it would be possible to use [TimerTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#timertrigger) in a continuous type to handle both cases.

I will try to see if that works. Please give your suggestions for this work case.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a single WebJob that is continuous. You can have as many functions that are decorated with TimerTrigger or message triggers as needed to respond to events or execute on a schedule. You are definitely on the right track.