# How to make Timer Trigger call the Queue Trigger with the help of the queue messages?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-triggers, timer-trigger, queuetrigger

For example,
I have 2 queue triggers which are to be called by 2 different messages of queue trigger in Timer Trigger function. How do I call the triggers in the timer and automate the messages so that when Timer function is triggered and it automatically sends messages to respective queues using python language?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the sample code for Timer trigger to call the queue trigger function.

[image]

host.json

```py
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

function.json

```py
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "*/20 * * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

for further information check the related [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65624919) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077022)